# Hi, I had a maven project ,while trying to maven clean i am getting the following error,anyone help me

Tags: maven-2

this is the error what i am getting ,war is generating but throwing error while trying to maven clean

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project ins-model: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete D:\VEMASVNINSURANCEWS\AIG\ins-parent\ins-model\target\surefire-reports -> [Help 1]
 Failed to execute goal-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project ins-model: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete ins-parent\ins-model\target\surefire-reports
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete D:\VEMASVNINSURANCEWS\AIG\ins-parent\ins-model\target\surefire-reports
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute(CleanMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]  <goals>  :ins-model
```

this is the error what i am getting ,war is generating but throwing error while trying to maven clean

Comment: Make sure, no program is using that war

Answer (score 1):

You are on Windows and you cannot delete the `target` folder (that's basically what `mvn clean`does) if any program is currently having a lock on something inside `target`.

According to your logs, that's the folder surefeire-report which is locked so: either your previous build is not finished and you have a Java thread still locking that folder or your have it opened in a console/browser.

Answer (score 0):

Some other process is using (parts of) the directory affected by clean (target). Some of the possible offenders:

- An application launched from the IDE earlier and still running.
- A directory nested within the parent directory (target) is opened in a file manager, it may lock parts of the content to be cleaned.